# Combining all the images in folder into a video

Tags: linux, image, bash, shell, raspberry-pi

I have a script that takes tons of pictures and names them with a time-stamp. These Images are all put into one folder. I want to create a script that takes all the pictures in the folder, combines them into a 10fps video, saves this video as the date and time it started from to the time it ended, and deletes the original pictures. So far, I've seen some people use Ffmpeg or mencoder but I'm not sure how to use these or do what I want with them. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the FFMpeg command line interface. You invoke it from the shell. Download the binary and run it by pointing it at the desired directory. %05d is simply string formatting for numbers. %05d just says pad with 4 leading zeros 0001.jpg or whatever.

```
# Create a directory and copy the original images there for manipulation:
mkdir temp
cp *.JPG temp/.
# Resize the images:
mogrify -resize 200x200  temp/*.JPG
# Create the morph images
convert temp/*.JPG -delay 10 -morph 5 temp/%05d.jpg
# Stitch them together into a video
ffmpeg -r 50 -qscale 2  -i temp/%05d.jpg output.mp4
```

from http://www.itforeveryone.co.uk/image-to-video.html